# AngularJs ng-change event fire manually

Tags: angularjs, onchange, angularjs-ng-change

```
 <input type="checkbox" value="" ng-model="filterPrivateDocCheckBox" ng-click="dl.filterPrivateDocument(filterPrivateDocCheckBox, $event)">
 <input st-search="target" class="input-sm form-control"  ng-model="dl.documentTarget" ng-change="dl.change()" />

function filterPrivateDocument(val) 
{
    if(val)
    this.documentTarget = 'Private';
}
```

When I clicked on checkBox I set the value into text box, but I saw `ng-change` event doesn't get fired. why?

And also When I type some value in text box I observe that `ng-change` event gets fired.

Any fix for this problem?

Comment: Can you provide a jsFiddle/Plunker where one can reproduce the problem?

Comment: So what is your problem here? The things you defined here is how your code is supposed to be working. What do want to be precisely?

Comment: What browser ???

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange):

> The ngChange expression is only evaluated when a change in the input value causes a new value to be committed to the model.
>
> It will not be evaluated:
>
> - if the value returned from the $parsers transformation pipeline has
>   not changed
> - if the input has continued to be invalid since the model
>   will stay null
> - **if the model is changed programmatically and not by a
>   change to the input value**

So it will not be triggered when it is changed by JavaScript (/angular).

What you can do, is trigger the change function yourself:

```
function filterPrivateDocument(val) {
    if(val) {
        this.documentTarget = 'Private';
        this.change();
    }
}
```

See [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x5wy7514/)

Comment: Thanks for your comment-3 highlighted in BOLD

Comment: strangely the 3rd point is exactly what's happening for me. can't figure out why but updating the value in the controller is in turn firing the ngChange 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46002276/angular-calling-ngchange-event-on-load-via-mysterious-eval-functionfilter